# make use of do loop for a variable specified in sed command

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

I have the following structure of data

```
HG2 MET 
HG1 THR
HG2 THR
HG2 GLN
```

The desire output would be

```
HG1 MET 
HG1 THR
HG2 THR
HG1 GLN
```

somehow I need to do the following

```
for i in MET GLN
do
sed 's/HG2 $i/HG1 $i/g'
done
```

or if it is possible to specify that I do not want to change the HG2 for THR but still change all the other instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the same with one run of `sed` for the whole file:

```
sed -E 's/HG2 (MET|GLN)/HG1 \1/' < oldfile > newfile
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I found the solution by simply adding double quotes such as

```
sed "s/HG2 $i/HG1 $i/g"
```